# Form data not saving data to database - Django

Tags: python, django, database, forms

I can't save form data to the database, everytime I try, I get a different error.

Here's my form model

```
    class Meta:
        model = Asistente
        exclude = ('evento',)
        widgets = {'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'telefono': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                   'num_asistentes': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})}
```

Here's the code to my view.

````
    def post(self, request, evento_id):
        evento = Evento.objects.filter(id=evento_id).first()
        form = RegistroAsistenteForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            registro_asistente = form.save(commit=False)
            registro_asistente.evento.pk = evento_id
            registro_asistente.save()
        else:
            form = RegistroAsistenteForm()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/evento-reg/' + str(evento_id) + '/asistente/')```

There are times when I don't get any error, it just don't do anything.
````

Comment: Because you always redirect, even when the form is invalid. You should only redirect when is_valid is true. But really, you shouldn't be writing your own post method at all; use a form view which does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

your view should look

````
def post(request, evento_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       evento = Evento.objects.filter(id=evento_id).first()
       form = RegistroAsistenteForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           registro_asistente.evento = evento
           form.save()
           #to get the id u can us form.instance.id
           return redirect('to what ever u want from you urls')

    else:
       form = RegistroAsistenteForm()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/evento-reg/' + str(evento_id) + '/asistente/')```
````

this is what gather what you want to do in views, it doesn't take self

Comment: I get this error now `post() got multiple values for argument 'evento_id'`

Comment: what are you  passsing in evento_id